# How to apply the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus

Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $\cos x\geq 1 - x$ if $x\gt 0$.

I'm unsure how to approach this problem. Can anyone give me any hints?

Comment: Using Grönwall's lemma you could just show that since $\cos 0 \ge 1$ and $-\sin x \ge -1$, $\cos x \ge 1-x$ for all $x\ge 0$

Answer (score 2):

Given $x > 0$, there exists $c \in (0,x)$ such that $\cos x - \cos 0 = -\sin(c)(x - 0)$, i.e.,

$$\cos x = 1 - (\sin c)x$$

Use the inequality $\sin c \le 1$ to finish.

Comment: I love how the shifting of a letter would give another function ^^ ($\mathrm{sinc}(x)$)